# Websocket reverse proxy with nginx: Error about request in server log, but works in browser

Tags: nginx, ip, reverse-proxy, ipv6, websocket

### The situation

I am running [Etherpad](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite), which is proxied via nginx. Etherpad uses Websockets with Socket.io.

My nginx config is more or less [this one](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy#from-subdirectory-url). The location block for socket.io is this:

```
rewrite /CustomSubDir/socket.io/(.*) /socket.io/$1 break;
proxy_pass http://localhost:CustomPort/;
proxy_redirect   / /CustomSubDir/;
proxy_cookie_path / /CustomSubDir/;

# usual proxy header
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

# websocket
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
# http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Host $host;

proxy_buffers 8 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;

proxy_buffering off;
```

### What's confusing

So the good message is: **Everything is working!** I am therefore not asking how to get anything working.
The bas one is: Although everything works nginx always shows me error messages.

### What's wrong

nginx shows me these errors in the `error.log`:

```
2016/05/24 xx:yy:zz [error] 22197#0: *12059 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: SOM.IPA.DDR.EES, server: somedomain.example.com, request: "GET /CustomSubDir/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1464121868147-3&sid=H2GhIY24t2a40etpAACd HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:CustomPort/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1464121868147-3&sid=H2GhIY24t2a40etpAACd", host: "somedomain.example.com"
2016/05/24 xx:yy:zz [error] 22197#0: *12070 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: SOM.IPA.DDR.EES, server: somedomain.example.com, request: "POST /CustomSubDir/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1464122037998-5&sid=T-pthraR669TF2cKAACe HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:CustomPort/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1464122037998-5&sid=T-pthraR669TF2cKAACe", host: "somedomain.example.com"
```

So I could trace this requests down. Here is why:
1. These are obviously Websocket requests.
2. And these are - and that's special - POST requests.

When loading an Etherpad or reconnecting to one after a lost connection only one request is made, which fulfils these requirements. I can clearly se it in the browser and can see it appearing in the nginx error log in real-time.
This is the request in my browser:

```
200 POST https://somedomain.example.com/CustomSubDir/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1464121868143-2&sid=H2GhIY24t2a40etpAACd
```

And it contains (e.g.) this payload:

```
164:42["message",{"component":"pad","type":"CLIENT_READY","padId":"CENSORED","sessionID":"null","password":null,"token":"t.qbszmj[...]","protocolVersion":2}]
```

The server reply is:

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 xx:yy:zz GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2
access-control-allow-origin: *
Set-Cookie: io=H2GhIY24t[...]
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

ok
```

#### Why I can be sure this is the culprit

I am very sure the POST request causes this. Not only because it is the only POST request with this URL when accessing the pad, I can also compare the behaviour.
Because on the same server I also run [Etherdraw](https://github.com/JohnMcLear/draw), which works very similar, but it has one important difference: It does not seem to use POST Websocket requests.
And guess what? The `error.log` is empty.

### My questions

So what are my questions:

1. How I can see the request to be successful in my browser (with a correct server reply!) while nginx reports me it is failing in the log?
2. How can I get rid of these error messages? AFAIK the requests do not fail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve my problem thanks to [@webzwo0i](https://github.com/webzwo0i), who [made me aware on GitHub](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/2992#issuecomment-221476080) that this might be an IPv4/IPv6 conflict.

So I again looked into the error logs and I noticed especially this:

> "[...] connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream[...]", upstream: "http://**[::1]**:CustomPort/socket.io/[...]"

This is the IPv6 localhost address, but Etherpad/NodeJS only seems to connect to the IPv4 address.

So changing all `localhost`s in the nginx config to `127.0.0.1` solved my problem. The errors in the log are gone.
I also noticed that some other requests also caused the same errors in the log, so it is not specific to the requests I described.